# Use a device in the board that is not listed in the schematic in Eagle

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

I am making the design of a PCB. The problem is that I need to use a device that is not listed in the schematic from a library that I downloaded. The next image shows how is not listed:

[image]

But it is in the board:

[image]

The problem comes when I try to place that device in the board since I get the next message:

[image]

I don't understand how I can backnotate this operation in the schematic if I don't have the symbol listed. Please help

Comment: Make a schematic symbol for it and leave it unconnected?

Comment: Make a schematic symbol with two ports and connect the ports to MSTB-02 as you shown in figure. You cannot directly place a PCB footprint in .brd file.